# Outlook Emails to assigning database

Tags: email, outlook

I'm def not looking for someone to do this project for me, just bouncing off some ideas with a guru or two.

I have emails going into a global box that is shared by a few employees. I need to find a better way to assign the work out. In the past, it was grab and go. Today, an employee assigns the work out.

I'm trying to find a simple way using maybe Excel or Access, that I could copy/drag the email and it would provide who should work it and how much work they have done by week/month/year.

It's not possible to use an inhouse ticketing system, because it is non employees that send mail to this inbox, so they would not have access to using the in house ticketing system.

Would it be easily possible to design something like this or is this a more daunting task? What software would you recommend or method would you use?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend converting emails to Tickets, using a CRM/ticketing system with such feature. It would save you the hassle of developing and mantaining custom code, for a commom feature needed not only by you, but many other firms:

A quick search for "convert emails to tickets" yielded:

- https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Mail_Converter
- http://community.geminiplatform.com/blogs/15/how-to-convert-emails-to-tickets-with-gemini

Both vTiger and Gemini are free to use.